# How do I change the colors in the rmdtemplate material theme?

Tags: r

I am using the rmdformats::material package.  What is the CSS to change the top banner color?

Here is my code.

````
---
title: "test"
date: "hi"
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    self_contained: no
    css: style.css
---


```{r knitr_init, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rmdformats)

```

# test
````

Here is  part of my CSS:

```
.page h1, .h1 {
    color: #971b72 ;
}
```

Comment: Hi MrFlick- thanks for the suggestion.  I added some of my code above.

Answer (score 1):

The banner color seems to be set as the background of the `.header-panel` div. You should set your CSS to

```
.header-panel {
    background-color: #971b72 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the background color of the header in your .css file with the following code:

```
.header-panel {
    background-color: #971b72;
}
```